# How do I convert EPOCH time to a time format (hh:mm)

Tags: c++, time, epoch, strftime

I have some EPOCH time values in a txt file which I need to read in then convert to a date and time. For example:1383260400. However for a particular function I would like to output only the time, in the format HH:MM. I have done my research but nothing seems to work. I tried the strftime fucntion but it does not work. 
I would therefore like to know how this can be achieved.
I am kind of new to C++ so I am unfamiliar with time functions.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems like you know the answer already, you do it with `strftime`. The documentation should have all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the C/C++ functions that utilize `time_t`:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::time_t secsSinceEpoch = 1383260400;
    std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&secsSinceEpoch), "%H:%M") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time_t and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time for more information.